# how to delete data with repository and service layer

Tags: laravel

I am going to delete a single record from the database and do so without using the hard code and using the repository and service layer.

This is my controller `AdminController.php`

```
<?php
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    private AdminService $admin_service;
    public function __construct(AdminService $admin_service)
    {
        $this->admin_service = $admin_service;
    }
    public function deleteAdmin(Request $request):RedirectResponse
    {
        
        return $this->admin_service->deleteAdmin($request);
    }
```

This is my repository `AdminRepository.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Interfaces\AdminRepositoryInterface as AdminRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\Admin;

class AdminRepository implements AdminRepositoryInterface
{
    public function deleteAdmin(Admin $admin)
    {
        $admin->delete();
    }
```

THis is my service layer interface `AdminServiceInterface.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Services\Interfaces;
interface AdminServiceInterface
{
    public function deleteAdmin(Admin $admin):RedirectResponse;
```

THis is my service layer `AdminService.php`

```
<?php
class AdminService implements AdminServiceInterface
{
    protected AdminRepository $admin_repository;
    public function __construct(AdminRepository $admin_repository)
    {
        $this->admin_repository = $admin_repository;
    }
    public function getAllAdmin():View
    {
        $admins = $this->admin_repository->getAllAdmin();
        return view('admins.list',['admins'=>$admins]);
    }
    public function deleteAdmin(Admin $admin):RedirectResponse
    {
        $this->admin_repository->deleteAdmin($admin);
        return redirect('admins');
    }
```

But I get the following error
‍‍`App\Services\AdminService::deleteAdmin(): Argument #1 ($admin) must be of type App\Models\Admin, Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /var/www/html/nft-market-admin/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php on line 56`

Answer (score 1):

You're passing whole `request`, which you shouldn't.

First Method :

In this case you're injecting `Admin $admin` in your `deleteAdmin` function, so if you're sending admin id in request, you should do like this :

```
In controller:
return $this->admin_service->deleteAdmin($request->adminId);
```

And of-course you should remember in this case, You've injected Admin Model in functions, and in this case you should always pass an instance of admin model(which in this case should be an existed result of an admin record) or pass ID of an existed admin matched in database.(When you pass ID instead of an instance of admin model, `Laravel` try to find a match base on admin ID).

Edit 01: I'll try to add more info in order to make sure you understand what you're doing.

```
This is an example.

in api.php/web.php
Route::get('deleteAdmin/{admin}, ... )
// Or
Route::delete('deleteAdmin/{admin}, ... ) (recommended method)
// Or
Route::post('deleteAdmin/{admin}, ... )
// Or
Route::post('deleteAdmin, ... )
```

So now base on above routes, which they're just examples, you should do like below in controller

```
For this method (Route::get('deleteAdmin/{admin}, ... )) :
public function deleteAdmin(Admin $admin):RedirectResponse
{   
    return $this->admin_service->deleteAdmin($admin);
}

For this method (Route::delete('deleteAdmin/{admin}, ... )) :
public function deleteAdmin(Admin $admin):RedirectResponse
{
    return $this->admin_service->deleteAdmin($admin);
}

For this method (Route::post('deleteAdmin/{admin}, ... )) :
public function deleteAdmin(Request $request):RedirectResponse
{   
    return $this->admin_service->deleteAdmin($request->adminId);
}

For this method (Route::post('deleteAdmin/{admin}, ... )) :
public function deleteAdmin(Request $request, Admin $admin):RedirectResponse
{
    return $this->admin_service->deleteAdmin($admin);
}

For this method (Route::post('deleteAdmin, ... )) :
public function deleteAdmin(Request $request):RedirectResponse
{
    return $this->admin_service->deleteAdmin($request->adminId);
}
```

Second Method :

Or just accept an ID in admin service like below (below workaround is basically working base on passing id to first function and finding admin, and passing instance of admin model to repository)

```
public function deleteAdmin(int $adminId):RedirectResponse
{
    $admin = $this->admin_repository->getAdmin($adminId);
    // You should add getAdmin to your repository.

    $this->admin_repository->deleteAdmin($admin);
    return redirect('admins');
}
```

Or In Admin Repository find the admin and delete it, which in this case you don't need to find admin in your delete admin service

```
Service
public function deleteAdmin(int $adminId):RedirectResponse
{
    $this->admin_repository->deleteAdmin($adminId);
    return redirect('admins');
}

Repo
class AdminRepository implements AdminRepositoryInterface
{
    public function deleteAdmin(int $adminId)
    {
        $admin = Admin::find($adminId);
        $admin->delete();
    }
```

Comment: I definitely want to get the **model** in the repository

Comment: Pleas help me :((((((((((((((

Comment: @samira I've got you 2 answer, you can use first method which is more accurate to what you've asked. but you can not pass request to it. what is in your request payload?

Comment: @samira I've updated answer but you should add more info regardless of how you're passing admin id, routes and etc.